# In case of multilevel/multiple inheritence, is there any best practice to invoke method from parent class?

Tags: python

Lets say we have multilevel inheritance:

```
Class A -> Class B -> Class C
```

Lets say each have method m defined.

obj=C().m  will call the method from class C.

In Class C, is there any best practice to call parent class method?

Example:

```
def Class B(A):
  ..def m..

def class C(B):
  ..init mtd here..
  def m:
    Print('In C')
```

Here within defn of m, if we wish to call parent class m method then we can either write B.m() or A.m() or both.

We could also invoke by using the super keyword. In this case, how do we target which parent class method is to be invoked? And is there any best practice

Comment: Can you format the code correctly, and give something more concrete and runnable?

Comment: it depends on your expectations when calling "parent" class in relation to abstraction and hierarchy